# How do I continue the display equations inside a frame when the page changes?

Tags: beamer, equations

How do I continue the display equations inside a frame when the page changes?
I have started with `\begin{frame}[t]` and the equations go beyond that page. Can I continue
the format of the equations on the next page?

```
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= e^{\int 1dx}\left(C+\int e^{\int(-1)dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^{\int dx}\left(C+\int e^{-\int dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x\left(C+\int e^{-x}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x(C+x).
\end{align*}
```

The third equation goes to the next page. If I started with anew align* command on the nest page, the equations on the two pages are not aligned right. I want the equality signs to be exactly on the same vertical line.
Actually, the third equation does not go the next page literally. It gets
cut off at the end of the page. I need to change the page in the middle of a display in the frame and continue the display on the next page. This is a very common and important problem. I am tired of trying to align the equations on the next page by starting a new frame there and using hskip many times to get the alignment straight.

Thank you!
latexatha

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can use in order to reproduce the output you get. Are your equations wider than the frame and overflow into the right margin or are there just way more equations than can fit into a slingle frame? Why not just split them up between two `frame` environments? What does "when the page changes" refer to exactly?

Comment: I have added the `beamer` tag since `begin{frame}[t] ` implies your documentclass is `beamer`.

Comment: Probably related: [Beamer: Split Align Environment Across Multiple Slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309569/134144)